# Registering new motion gestures in Tizen for wearable

Tags: gesture, tizen-wearable-sdk

Got a bit of a last minute project for uni. I'm trying to develop an application for a Samsung wearable where you can use motion gestures to interact with IoT devices(like lights and music).

I'm looking at this sample (https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen-CSharp-Samples/tree/master/Wearable/Xamarin.Forms/GestureSensor) using gesture detector. Not sure how to register new motion gestures. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to make a new gesture?
But there are specific types of gesture.
You can use "face down, pick up and wrist up" gesture in Tizen C# app.
(https://samsung.github.io/TizenFX/stable/api/Tizen.Sensor.Sensor.html)

If you develop with Tizen native app, there are more types of gestures such as shaking, tilting, and snapping.
(https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/wearable/5.0/group__CAPI__CONTEXT__GESTURE__MODULE.html#ga260f6752298cdd6c8235fd2922c147bf)

If these are not enough, you should detect them directly using an acceleration sensor or a gyroscope sensor.

Comment: That's great thanks, yes indeed, I'd like to record new gestures if possible. I'm hoping to detect a wave, pinch and twist (for volume adjustment). 

I've seen sample apps that show the outputs from the sensors, but I'm unsure how I would use this data to register new gestures.

Perhaps printing the output range and storing that but unsure on the format.

I'm an absolute novice so any direction is helpful

Comment: You can get the measured values of sensors including accelerometer and gyroscope.
(https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen-CSharp-Samples/tree/master/Wearable/Xamarin.Forms/Sensors)

I think it is possible that you check the values of sensors when you do the gesture you want.
For example, if I turn my palm down, the sign of the z-value of the accelerometer becomes -. (maybe...)